# finding a valley with Matlab in a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image like that:

[image: example of binary image]

I know the position of one point in the black region (for example, the X point) and I need to find the valley (the point with lowest Y coordinate) in the same black region (in this example, the O point).

There are other black regions in the image.

How can I do this using Matlab?

Comment: you mean the lowest Y coordinate? Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: yes, I mean lowest. sorry. I don't have any code, I'm new in image processing and I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a starting point P=(x,y), you can use imfill in order to find the corresponding connected component, and combination of max and imfind in order to find the lowest point within it.

```
%reads the image
I = imread('<your path>');

%sets an input point. For example: (250,100)
x = 100; y=250;

%Find the connected component of the given input point
BW2 = imfill(I,[y x]);
diffMat = BW2~=I;

%finds the minimal x and y indices of this connected component
[Y, X] = ind2sub(size(diffMat),find(diffMat));
maxInd = find(Y==max(Y),1,'first');

%prints the result
Y(maxInd)
X(maxInd)
```

given the following input:

[image]

the result is:

```
Y=313, X=304
```

Notice that this code finds only one point as a valley. if you want to find more points, you can omit this parameter from find function and receive all the valley points.

Comment: You don't have to have a starting point if you use [`bwlabel`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html)